# Using javascript to change table cell background color based on json value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display status of clients (up or down) by changing the color table cell background based on json value:

```
[{
    "client": "client1",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "status": "up"
}, {
    "client": "client2",
    "ip": "127.0.0.2",
    "status": "up"
}]
```

My attempt so far:

```
<script>
$.getJSON("<webaddress>/clients.json",
function (data) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);


        if(data[i].status == "up")
        {
          $('td').css ('background-color', 'green');
         } else {
          $('td').css('background-color', 'red');
         };    

}


});


</script>

<style type="text/css">

.table {
  width: 300px !important;
}

</style>

<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Clients</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

When status is up the cell background stays green but even if I change one status to down then all cell background turns red. I know its probably something obviously, but it doesnt help that my js knowledge is not that good.

Comment: Re `tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client + "</td>");`: Strongly recommend **not** using string concatenation of raw values to HTML strings when creating elements; suppose `data[i].client` has an `&` or `<` in it? Instead: `tr.append($("<td>").text(data[i].client));`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I am going to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap, by that code

```
$('td').css ('background-color', 'green');
```

your all TDs will be green.

To color required td, you need to change it to

```
$('td',tr).css ('background-color', 'green');
```

Comment: Note that `$('td,tr)` just turns around and calls `tr.find('td')`.

Comment: yeap, it is an equivalent

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had to remove the else statement and I also made the default color red for `tr td { background-color: red; }`

Comment: The point isn't that it's equivalent, it's that when you call `$('td', tr)`, what jQuery does is some work to figure out that's what you've done, and then it **literally** calls `tr.find('td')` and returns the result.

Comment: @bran: The `else` should be fine provided you do the same thing there that Nigrimmist pointed out above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried it but for some reason it wasn't working. So I went for the other method.

Comment: Unrelated question, if I were to auto reload json file without having to do a full refresh what do I have to do?

Comment: @bran in that case you need to associate every td with row from json, by any id. And search it - if exist, just change color without add to DOM.

Comment: @Nigrimmist I don't know how I should go about doing it, any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: @bran when you receive json, iterate it and in frist time set attribute $('td',tr).attr('client',clientFromJson); Next time, you don't need to create new tds, you only need iterate json and get required td. smth like that : $('td[client='+clientFromJson+']') - your client's TD. That's in case  when client's ip was changed or something like that. If you like full refresh - just clear table and fill it again. $(table).html('') or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$('td')` which means all the td tag in the document so change that to `tr.find('td')` there are many other ways to do it. Hope it will work for you